# Bootstrap size variable in Angular controllers/services?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use a variable which stores what Bootstrap3 breakpoint(xs,sm,md,lg)  the webpage currently is at to do things in Angular services/controllers (like on desktop I'd open a Kendo-UI window but on mobile I'd use a simple 100% width window).

Is there a way to set something like this up?

Comment: If you really need it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia.  Doesn't have support in IE<10. http://caniuse.com/#search=matchmedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set a variable to bootstraps specific breakpoints and change the value of that variable to 'xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg' with a 'watch' on the window resize.

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
  //set a $scope variable or a service variable that reused
  $scope.bootstrap_size = 'xs';
  $scope.is_mobile = true;
  if($window.innerWidth >=1200) {    
    $scope.bootstrap_size = 'lg';
    $scope.is_mobile = false;  
  } else if($window.innerWidth >= 992) {
    $scope.bootstrap_size = 'md';
    $scope.is_mobile = false;  
  } else if($window.innerWidth >= 768) {
    $scope.bootstrap_size = 'sm';
    $scope.is_mobile = false;  
  }
});
```

If dont need to have those values in angular, and if just need to see the breakpoint values in a debug toolbar can also just use default bootstrap classes to achieve this:

```
<div class="visible-xs"><strong>sz:</strong>xs</div>
<div class="visible-sm"><strong>sz:</strong>sm</div>
<div class="visible-md"><strong>sz:</strong>md</div>
<div class="visible-lg"><strong>sz:</strong>lg</div>
```

Comment: This is nothing major, but one thing you might want to consider for your if statements to work properly would be to switch the order of your if statements. The first case is going to be hit if the size of the screen is small, medium, or large. This may help someone in the future.